# Powershell script as a Topshelf/Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, service, topshelf

I'd like to get notified when a specific pattern occurs in some text file so I wrote a simple PowerShell script:

```
Get-Content 'C:\\testfile.txt' -Wait -Tail 50 | Select-String -Pattern 'Sample pattern'
```

I'd rather run it as a topshelf service. I've already produced the following code:

```
public class MyService
{
    private string doWork;

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return @"C:\\testfile.txt";
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        while (this.doWork)
        {
            var script = $"Get-Content '{Path}' -Wait -Tail 50 | Select-String -Pattern 'Sample pattern'";
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script);
                var PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
                {
                    if (outputItem != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject + "\n");
                    }
                }

                if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write.Write("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.doWork = false;
    }

}


public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rc = HostFactory.Run(
            x =>
                {
                    x.Service<MyService>(
                        s =>
                            {
                                s.ConstructUsing(name => new MyService());
                                s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                                s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
                            });
                    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                    x.StartAutomatically();
                    x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host");
                    x.SetDisplayName("Sample display name");
                    x.SetServiceName("Sample service name");
                });

        var exitCode = (int)Convert.ChangeType(rc, rc.GetTypeCode());
        Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;
    }
}
```

The solutions builds fine.I ran it in a debug mode, but for some reason I don't see the expected output on the console so I assume that there is some problem which I tried to figure out myself but without effect.
Is there any way to make this program working as expected? If anyone could provide some guidance or even proper solution I'd be grateful.

Comment: [`PowerShell.Streams`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#properties) has more than just `Error`. Try checking and writing to the console for all the streams (`Debug`, `Error`, `Information`, `Progress`, `Verbose`, and `Warning`).

Comment: FYI this will fail if you deploy it as a service, as the Service Control Manager will see that Start hasn't returned, and assume the service has failed to install, See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495731/43846) or for more detail [this issue](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/183)